# Is there any work around to launch screen flow from Process builder

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, oob

I have  a requirement where I need to provide a modal window to user when Case status changes to Revise Invoice status .

He can then select Account and a child case gets created under that account .

Now I want to use OOB feature to achieve this .

Having a screen and creating a child case ,can be achieved by Screen flow .

But now I am stuck as how to call screen flow from process builder or an auto triggered flow .
Is there any way that can make my screen flow connect with process builder or to have this requirement without writing any code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem is that there will be no way to show this modal for updates that are triggered from non-UI (data loader, apex, other automations etc).
Therefore my advice would be to revise that process to make the changes to start from UI (not via field update on standard page layout, but rather via quick action and flow or custom developments)

Comment: ok but for quick action ill need a button . So that means calling a screen flow for a status change is only possible though custom dev here